# Does the plutus playground make all defined function inlinable by defauld?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I noticed that not in all of the examples on the playground the `{-# INLINABLE myProgram #-}` flag is used. Does the playground natively accept every function as template haskell? Why do some examples not need it?